# SQL update row if key exists else update a default row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is what I am trying to do (in pseudo code)

```
if (dB entry exists) {
  UPDATE the dB entry
}else{
  UPDATE a default dB entry
}
```

This is not a "`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE`" question.
I'm hoping there is some kind of `UPDATE ... ON DUPLICATE` type of slick code to do this in one line.

My code creates `$userName` from the `$_GET['U']` request.  If `$userName` exists in the database (it's a unique key), then increment a counter in the database.  Else, increment a counter for a default entry.

Here is my current code to update the counter:

```
$userName = $_GET['U'];
$sql = "UPDATE `stats` SET `count`= `count` + 1 WHERE `userName` = '" . $userName . "'";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

And if this particular username doesn't exist, I want this to happen:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `stats` SET `count`= `count` + 1 WHERE `userName` = 'default'";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: @CodingAnt, I'm trying to minimize the amount of load on the server by making the code more efficient and eliminating one touch on the DB.  Your code below was my original / traditional way of implementing the pseudo code; Since I already use `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE` elsewhere in my code, it had me wondering if there was a similar solution for `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this,

```
$userName = $_GET['U'];

$query_uname_exists = "SELECT count(*) FROM stats WHERE `userName` = '" . $userName . "'";

$uname_count        =  mysqli_query($conn,$query_uname_exists);

if($uname_count > 0){
    #update

$sql = "UPDATE `stats` SET `count`= `count` + 1 WHERE `userName` = '" . $userName . "'";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

}
else{
    #update default

    $sql = "UPDATE `stats` SET `count`= `count` + 1 WHERE `userName` = 'default'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most I can shrink it for you:

```
$userName = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT count(*) FROM stats WHERE `userName` = '".$_GET['U']."' LIMIT 1") == 0 ? 'default' : $_GET['U'];
mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `stats` SET `count`= `count` + 1 WHERE `userName` = '".$userName."' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query

```
$sql = "Update stats SET count = count + 1 where username =  (case when username= ". $userName ". then username else 'default' end)";
```

Comment: I did not know about `CASE...WHEN`; thanks for introducing that to me.  

This code does work if the row DOESN'T exist (it updates the "default" row).  However, if the row DOES exist, it increments both "default" AND the existing rows.   
For example.
``UPDATE `stats` SET `count` = `count` + 1 where `userName` =  (case WHEN `userName`='mary' then 'mary' else 'default' end)``

If the row with "mary" exists, both "default" and "mary" counts are incremented.  

BTW, is your syntax slightly off?  I believe you meant to have: `(case when username= ". $userName ". then " . $userName . " else ...`

Comment: As the $username is an string that's why it should be in the single quote, and i don't know why it is updating to both rows. because case will only return only value either $username or default and it should update accordingly. it is surprising for me if it is updating the both. also the "=" works for only one record. :)